# Singular Matrix Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working to implement a Least Squares Estimate using Matrices.  However, I seem to produce a Singular Matrix which means I cannot solve the equation.  I'm struggling to understand why the matrix is singular (I know about determinants, etc) - is there something obvious that I am missing?

The system I am working with is as follows:

$$ X = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_1^2}{y_1^2} & \frac{x_1y_1}{y_1^2} & \frac{x_1}{y_1^2} & \frac{y_1}{y_1^2} & \frac{1}{y_1^2} \\
\frac{x_2^2}{y_2^2} & \frac{x_2y_2}{y_2^2} & \frac{x_2}{y_2^2} & \frac{y_2}{y_2^2} & \frac{1}{y_2^2} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{x_k^2}{y_k^2} & \frac{x_ky_k}{y_k^2} & \frac{x_k}{y_k^2} & \frac{y_k}{y_k^2} & \frac{1}{y_k^2}
\end{pmatrix} \\
P =  \begin{pmatrix}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
E 
\end{pmatrix}
 $$

$ P $ is a vector of unknowns, I am trying to find estimates for $ P $ with the following equation:

$$ P_{est} = \left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X $$

Now, the Matrix $ \left(X^TX\right)^{-1} $ is always singular for my data, I have even tried putting in random data which also gives a singular Matrix.  With this in mind I suspect there is a property of the Matrix definition itself which is causing the issue but I can't put my finger on it.

Do any of you clever people know why this is happening?  I can and will provide data once I return to work.

Thankyou.

Update - I have scaled the data and I still get a Singular Matrix - what is causing this?

Given the following data:

$$ \begin{matrix}
X & Y \\
13.7284650 & 12.2143600 \\
13.7284650 & 12.2143600 \\
12.2198090 & 12.2098100 \\
12.2077710 & 13.7148230 \\
\end{matrix} $$

Will produce the following Matrix:

$$ X = \begin{pmatrix}
1.263 & 1.124 & 0.092 & 0.082 & 6.703E-3 \\
1.002 & 1.001 & 0.082 & 0.082 & 6.708E-3 \\
0.792 & 0.89 & 0.065 & 0.073 & 5.316E-3 \\
0.723 & 0.85 & 0.059 & 0.07 & 4.863E-3 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Transposing gives:

$$ X^T = \begin{pmatrix}
1.263 & 1.002 & 0.792 & 0.723 \\
1.124 & 1.001 & 0.89 & 0.85 \\
0.092 & 0.082 & 0.065 & 0.059 \\
0.082 & 0.082 & 0.073 & 0.07 \\
6.703E-3 & 6.708E-3 & 5.316E-3 & 4.863E-3 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Therefore $ X^TX $ gives:

$$ X^TX = \begin{pmatrix}
3.7499 & 3.7425 & 0.2927 & 0.2937 & 0.0229 \\
3.7425 & 3.7804 & 0.2937 & 0.2982 & 0.0231 \\
0.2927 & 0.2937 & 0.0229 & 0.0231 & 1.8001E-3 \\
0.2937 & 0.2982 & 0.0231 & 0.0236 & 1.8249E-3 \\
0.0229 & 0.0231 & 1.8001E-3 & 1.8249E-3 & 1.4184E-4 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Which has has determinant 0, and therefore cannot be inverted.

Why is this?  I suspect it's something to do with diagonality?  Is there a way around this to solve the equation?

Any help/advice appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Is your data complex? If so you need to use $*$.

Comment: Hi, no the data is not complex.  It is X,Y data from an ADC, 24 bit.  It is typically in the region of 10,000,000 to 14,000,000.

Comment: @MikeShaw: It sounds like you need to scale your data down. It could be that the right hand column is causing you trouble, as well as those nearby it. Afterall you are squaring stuff so you'll be seeing $10^{-14}$ magnitudes, which could be causing your inversion algorithm problems.

Comment: @Alex: Thankyou, will try that on Tues when back at work and report back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$X$ is 'fat' (that is has more columns than rows). So you don't want to be computing the 'least squares solution' (there are many such solutions, thus the reason that $X^TX$ is singular).

Let me elaborate, consider the problem: Given some $n\times m$ matrix $A$ and vector $y$, find a vector $x$ such that

$$y=Ax.\quad\quad\quad(*)$$

Assume that $A$ is full rank (that is, rank$(A)=min(n,m)$).

If $A$ is square, there is a unique $x$ that satisfies $(*)$ and it is given by

$$x=A^{-1}y.$$

If $A$ is 'skinny' there will most likely be (for all $y$ except those that lie in some subspace) no vector $x$ that exactly satisfies $(*)$. That is why we compute the 'least squares solution' (or 'least square *approximate* solution') of $(*)$. That is, the vector $x$ that minimizes the square error between $y$ and $Ax$, $||y-Ax||_{2}^2$. It can be shown that the least square solution is given by

$$x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty.$$

If $A$ is 'fat', then for a single vector $y$ there will be many vectors $x$ that satisfy $(*)$. What people often do in this case is pick the 'minimum norm solution'. That is, the vector $x$ with smallest $||x||_2$ that satisfies $(*)$. It turns out that this can be computed as

$$x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}y.$$

For a much better and thorough explanation of the above (with the derivations of the different solutions) see lectures 6-9 of [this](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=17005383-19c6-49ed-9497-2ba8bfcfe5f6).

Comment: That is brilliant, very clear and I understand it.  Thankyou very much.  I will play around with those equations and see what I can derive.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: Slides for the minimum norm solution in the case of a 'fat' $A$ are available here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee263/ee263.1042/min-norm